# How to get specific characters from column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Please help me how to get specific characters in SQL Server.

[image: screenshoot]

to:

[image]

Rules:

- column a only select 6 characters after '='
- column b get character between '_' and ','
- column c get character between '_' and ','

Data sample:

```
eNodeB Function Name=SMD085ML1_CIMANGLID, Local Cell ID=21, Cell Name=C_SMD085ML1_CIMANGLIDML2, eNodeB ID=160085, Cell FDD TDD indication=CELL_FDD
eNodeB Function Name=CRB325ML_KEJAKSAANCRB, Local Cell ID=31, Cell Name=CRB325ML_KEJAKSAANCRBML3, eNodeB ID=154325, Cell FDD TDD indication=CELL_FDD
eNodeB Function Name=CRB612ML_PILANGSARI, Local Cell ID=31, Cell Name=CRB612ML_PILANGSARIML3, eNodeB ID=154612, Cell FDD TDD indication=CELL_FDD
```

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 2):

You can use CHARINDEX to find the position of a specific character in a given string
The you can use SUBSTRING function to fetch a string value in a desired length

Please check following syntax

```
declare @str varchar(100) =  'aerwagf=werweyyqasdwe3289afa'

select SUBSTRING(@str, CHARINDEX('=', @str)+1, 6)
```

For the text between two specific characters, you can refer to following SQL functions and their usages in below query

```
declare @str varchar(100) =  'aerwagf=werweyyqasd-we3289afa'

select
    CHARINDEX('=',@str,1),
    CHARINDEX('-',@str,CHARINDEX('=',@str,1)),
    SUBSTRING(
        @str, 
        CHARINDEX('=',@str,1)+1,
        (CHARINDEX('-',@str,CHARINDEX('=',@str,1)) - CHARINDEX('=',@str,1)) - 1
    )
```

After @Shnugo's message I applied the solution to your sample data 
The query is now as follows

```
select
    SUBSTRING(a, CHARINDEX('=', a)+1, 6) as A, -- OK
    SUBSTRING(
        b, 
        CHARINDEX('_',b,1)+1,
        (CHARINDEX(',',b,CHARINDEX('_',b,1)) - CHARINDEX('_',b,1)) - 1
    ) as B,
    SUBSTRING(
        c, 
        CHARINDEX('_',c,1)+1,
        (CHARINDEX(',',c,CHARINDEX('_',c,1)) - CHARINDEX('_',c,1)) - 1
    ) as C
from TextTable
```

And the produced output is

[image]

Comment: This is a hint in the right direction... But try to use this on a table's data and find the second `=` and the following `_` in one go... Possible... But unreadable...

Comment: Hi, great, did not want to push you :-D I tried your new query against my mockup table and column b an c are the same. Don't know, where your `a, b and c` come from, but you find the third result *behind* the second `Name=`...

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion will split this at `Name=` first and then handle the parts separately:

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(YourString VARCHAR(500));
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES
 ('eNodeB Function Name=SMD085ML1_CIMANGLID, Local Cell ID=21, Cell Name=C_SMD085ML1_CIMANGLIDML2, eNodeB ID=160085, Cell FDD TDD indication=CELL_FDD')
,('eNodeB Function Name=CRB325ML_KEJAKSAANCRB, Local Cell ID=31, Cell Name=CRB325ML_KEJAKSAANCRBML3, eNodeB ID=154325, Cell FDD TDD indication=CELL_FDD')
,('eNodeB Function Name=CRB612ML_PILANGSARI, Local Cell ID=31, Cell Name=CRB612ML_PILANGSARIML3, eNodeB ID=154612, Cell FDD TDD indication=CELL_FDD');


WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(m.YourString,'Name=','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS ToXml
    FROM @mockupTable AS m
)
SELECT LEFT(A.Part1,6) AS a
      ,SUBSTRING(A.Part1,Pos1_Underscore+1,Pos1_Comma-Pos1_Underscore-1) AS b
      ,SUBSTRING(A.Part2,Pos2_Underscore+1,Pos2_Comma-Pos2_Underscore-1) AS c
FROM Splitted
CROSS APPLY(SELECT ToXml.value('/x[2]','nvarchar(max)') AS Part1
                  ,ToXml.value('/x[3]','nvarchar(max)') AS Part2) AS A 
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX('_',A.Part1,6) AS Pos1_Underscore
                  ,CHARINDEX('_',A.Part2,6) AS Pos2_Underscore
                  ,CHARINDEX(',',A.Part1) AS Pos1_Comma
                  ,CHARINDEX(',',A.Part2) AS Pos2_Comma) AS B;
```

The result

```
a       b               c
SMD085  CIMANGLID       CIMANGLIDML2
CRB325  KEJAKSAANCRB    KEJAKSAANCRBML3
CRB612  PILANGSARI      PILANGSARIML3
```

Using `CROSS APPLY` allows to create better readable code. You can use the computed columns like a named variable...